# Was Harry Potter killed and then brought back to life?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

In the last movie, Harry was struck by the Avada Kedavra spell cast by Voldemort. Really, he should be dead. But obviously he was not dead because when Narcissa Malfoy (Draco's mother) asked about the life/death of her son, there was a pause hinting that Harry was talking to the woman. And knowing Malfoy is not dead, in return, the woman declared Harry was dead.

However, one should really be dead if struck by the Avada Kedavra spell.  Does this indicate the work of the Resurrection Stone?

Comment: I hate the movie for not explaining this.

Comment: @Javier: I hate people which refer to the movie and not to the book! :-)

Comment: I finished the book 4 years ago ( I think it is 4 ) and forget about the details.

Comment: I hate people who think books should be necessary to understand the movies.

Comment: Well I might as well continue the theme.. I hate how people who have only seen the film are under the impression they are knowledgeable enough to answer questions about anything other than the film and only the film. But in the end as long as they enjoy [it] that's what matters. Even if they're wrong which if it's only based on the film they probably are; and of course the books are always better though my brother makes a valid point: if he isn't going to read the book then the book isn't 'better' in a sense (though I don't agree entirely with that).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, Harry dropped the Stone before his encounter with Voldemort in the Forbidden Forest.
If he survived, it's because :

> When Harry met Voldemort in the Forbidden Forest, Voldemort used the Killing Curse on him almost immediately, but only destroyed the Horcrux, rendering his scar "normal." What was not revealed to Voldemort was that **when he used Harry's blood three years prior to gain himself a new body, the blood passed Harry's mother's protection to Voldemort and anchored Harry to the living world through Voldemort.** Harry was merely knocked to the ground and feigned death. Voldemort, as a result of destroying his soul shard in Harry, was also knocked out
>   - [Harry Potter wiki, "Tom Riddle" article, "Final battle and death" section](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Riddle#Final_battle_and_death)

Comment: Why I don't understand why he dropped the stone. It is one of the 3 deathly hallows!

Comment: @gunbuster363 http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4610/45

Comment: There's also the fact that the Elder Wand's allegiance was to Harry, not Voldemort.  When Voldemort cast the Killing Curse at a body with two souls, it killed the soul with which it was *not* aligned (the horcrux).

Comment: "anchored Harry to the living world through Voldemort" So basically Voldemort became a Horcrux for Harry??

Answer (score 9):

Harry Potter clearly did die. This is clear from, for example, the discussion revealed in Snape's memory between Snape and Dumbledore where it is explained to Snape that the only way to defeat Voldemort is for Potter to die.

What is not clear is how Potter comes back as neither the book nor the movie make any attempt to explain it. But his death is clearly necessary for Voldemort's defeat.

Comment: Snape and Dumbledore were wrong.  Harry didn't have to die, but the part of Big V's soul that was in him did.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't think Dumbledore was wrong. Yes, he _told_ Snape that Harry had to die, but that doesn't mean he really thought so. In the end, the only thing necessary thing was that Harry had to be _convinced_ he had to die, and Harry seeing that memory of Snape helped convince Harry.

Answer (score 8):

Harry Potter did not die. Instead of killing Harry, Voldemort's *Avada Kedavra* killed the piece of his own soul that was attached to Harry and that made him the seventh Horcrux. Obviously the spell was powerful enough to *nearly* kill Harry as well, but as Dumbledore says, "Voldemort has clearly always underestimated the power of an intact soul". Harry had a choice at "King's Cross"; he could head back to the world of the living and try to make a difference, or he could "take a train". Harry's will to finish the fight led him to choose the former.

Comment: So if V's killing curse only acted on the horcrux in Harry, then what was Dumbledore in "King's Cross"? Was it Dumbledore himself, or just a figment of Harry's own mind?

Comment: You could think of it as Harry having a near-death experience. As Dumbledore said: "Of course it's happening inside your head, Harry, but why should that mean it isn't real?".

Answer (score 2):

As Dumbledore explains to Harry while in "King's Cross", Voldemort made seven Horcruxes (soul was split into 8 parts, including voldemort's own body). The last one he never intended to make, and that Horcrux was Harry. So, rather than killing Harry, Voldemort unintentionally killed the Horcrux he never meant to make.

Comment: I think it was only 7 in total: diary, ring, locket, cup, diadem, Nagini, Harry. Did I miss anything? Funny thing though... in the movie, Tom talks to Slughorn about splitting his soul into seven pieces - suggesting intent to create 7 horcruxes... or only 6 for each horcrux + his own remaining self?

Comment: “He made *seven* Horcruxes?” said Harry, horror-struck, while several of the portraits on the wall made similar noises of shock and outrage.  “But they could be anywhere in the world — hidden — buried or invisible —”          ¶          “I am glad to see you appreciate the magnitude of the problem,” said Dumbledore calmly.  “But firstly, no, Harry, not seven Horcruxes: six.  The seventh part of his soul, however maimed, resides inside his regenerated body.  …” — *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 23: “Horcruxes”

Comment: … Dumbledore smiled.  /  “You were the seventh Horcrux, Harry, the Horcrux he never meant to make.  …  He left part of himself latched to you, the would-be victim who had survived.”    ¶    …     ¶    “He took your blood believing it would strengthen him.  He took into his body a tiny part of the enchantment your mother laid upon you when she died for you.  His body keeps her sacrifice alive, and while that enchantment survives, so do you ….” — *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 35, “King’s Cross”

Comment: So, whether it’s seven or eight depends on whether you count Voldemort’s body as a Horcrux.  But Dumbledore didn’t.

Comment: @PeregrineRook fixed!

Answer (score 2):

## Harry didn’t really die - his blood in the Dark Lord tied him to life.

After the Killing Curse hit him, Harry asks Dumbledore if he’s dead, and Dumbledore says no.

> “Then … I’m dead too?’
>
> ‘Ah,’ said Dumbledore, smiling still more broadly. ‘That is the question, isn’t it? On the whole, dear boy, I think not.’
>
> They looked at each other, the old man still beaming.
>
> ‘Not?’ repeated Harry.
>
> ‘Not,’ said Dumbledore.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross)*</sup></sub>

The reason for this, Dumbledore goes on to explain, is that the Dark Lord taking his blood tethered him to life while the Dark Lord lived, since Lily’s protection was then inside them both.

> “He took your blood believing it would strengthen him. He took into his body a tiny part of the enchantment your mother laid upon you when she died for you. His body keeps her sacrifice alive, and while that enchantment survives, so do you and so does Voldemort’s one last hope for himself.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 35 (King’s Cross)*</sup></sub>

Harry’s blood in the Dark Lord tied him to life, so he didn’t truly die. He was further helped by being the true master of the Elder Wand. It didn’t want to kill its master, so the Killing Curse it cast against him wasn’t as powerful as it could have been. It had nothing to do with the Resurrection Stone - that only brings back the “shadows” of people who are already dead, it doesn’t prevent death.

Answer (score 1):

He was shot with Avada Kedavra, but he never died. Voldemort had killed a part of himself.

Answer (score -2):

Harry possesed the 3 Deathly Hallows. He was the master of death, and thus he could chose to come back to life.

Comment: He did not possess all three hallows when he died. And your assertion on his being able to choose to come back to life is not obvious at all, on what do you base this?

Comment: @Gilles: Because Dumbledore told him so in the "dream."